# OnsenUI showing pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onsen-ui

I have the current setup for my project:

```
<div ons-if-orientation="landscape">
  <ons-split-view secondary-page="app/views/menu.html" main-page="app/views/main.html" main-page-width="80%" collapse="portrait">
  </ons-split-view>
</div>

<div ons-if-orientation="portrait">
  <ons-sliding-menu max-slide-distance="260px" menu-page="app/views/menu.html" main-page="app/views/main.html" type="push" var="menu">
  </ons-sliding-menu>
</div>
```

show this shows a split view when on landscape and a slidemenu when on portrait,

And as main page the following is in my html:

```
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()" ons-if-orientation="portrait">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center">Main page</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <br>
            <ons-button modifier="light"
                        onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('app/views/buildings/buildings.html', { animation : 'slide' } )">
                Show buildings
            </ons-button>
        </div>
    </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

but now I want to change it to show actual pages when I click on buttons in my navigation or in the main page

I tried doing the following:

```
<ons-button modifier="light" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('app/views/buildings/buildings.html', { animation : 'slide' } )">
    Show buildings
</ons-button>
```

but nothing happens, any clue why this is happening? following pen shows this behavior in action: http://codepen.io/cskiwi/pen/JdzrXE?editors=100

EDIT: found out this behaviour is only on webbrowsing, when opening this on my android device, this started working

Answer (score 2):

It works on your android device because it's orientation is portrait, while the one of your pc browser is landscape. If you manipulate the dimension of the window, you'll notice that it works also on your pc browser.

The main issue is that you have two instances of the same navigator.

```html
<div ons-if-orientation="landscape">
  <ons-split-view secondary-page="app/views/menu.html" main-page="app/views/main.html" main-page-width="80%" collapse="portrait">
  </ons-split-view>
</div>

<div ons-if-orientation="portrait">
  <ons-sliding-menu max-slide-distance="260px" menu-page="app/views/menu.html" main-page="app/views/main.html" type="push" var="menu">
  </ons-sliding-menu>
</div>
```

The same page, `menu.html`, has been created twice, with the same navigator. One of the two will be hidden when the other one is visualized, but they are both still there.

The easiest solution is to create two different main pages which contain different navigators. This means that you have to adapt all your navigation pattern.

[HERE](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/gpEGVJ) you can find a working CodePen example, I created another main page and renamed the previous one. Now there are two main pages, called `mainL.html` and `mainP.html` which contain, respectively, `myNavigatorL` and `myNavigatorP`. (please not that I didn't change the navigation pattern after the first iteration).

Comment: Just what I said realy couple of seconds ago! :)

Comment: @Kiwi  Ahahahaha, I'm glad you understood by yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the code was working but as I said only on the mobile version, this was because it could only switch 1 view so I made 2 navigators working in tandem:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ons-if-orientation="landscape">
        <ons-split-view
                secondary-page="app/views/menu.html"
                main-page="navigatorLand.html"
                main-page-width="80%"
                collapse="portrait"
                var="splitview">
        </ons-split-view>
    </div>

    <div ons-if-orientation="portrait">
        <ons-sliding-menu
                max-slide-distance="260px"
                menu-page="app/views/menu.html"
                main-page="navigatorPort.html"
                type="push"
                var="menu">
        </ons-sliding-menu>
    </div>

    <ons-template id="navigatorPort.html">
        <ons-navigator var="navPort"></ons-navigator>
    </ons-template>
    <ons-template id="navigatorLand.html">
        <ons-navigator var="navLand"></ons-navigator>
    </ons-template>
</div>
```

and then creating a function:

```
$scope.gotoPage = function (url) {
    navLand.pushPage(url);
    navPort.pushPage(url);
};
$scope.back = function () {
    navLand.popPage();
    navPort.popPage();
};
```